# Google Sheets get user Time IN and Out and consolidate data into another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I am new here and have little to no knowledge on google sheets formula.
The problem is I am trying to get the User Time In and Out from a google form responses Sheet. to another sheet where the data will be consolidated to each respective user.

So far I have put a ID to each user
[image: Sample]

Comment: Can you ***manually*** add the ideal expected output for one day (maybe Jan 9th)?! bcoz it kinda looks like some folks from Jan9 could be logging out on Jan10 & the OUTs we find on Jan9 could be of those who logged in on Jan8 and so on!

Comment: Hi Yes there are folk who is logging on the night and logging out in the morning the next day for night duty.

Sample output is like below should be. thanks
https://imgur.com/a/esha3Uj

Comment: ID "230310"  and "190245" Logged OUT on office via biometrics therefore no data for google forms.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out (for jan9):*

***UPDATED FORMULA***

```js
=let(Σ,importrange("1pRfiwKbCux-_7IvlFYRtivvqtOOZfqJu5HW0CS3bcg4","A:E"),
     Ξ,map(A9:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,+ifna(filter(index(Σ,,2),int(index(Σ,,1))=E6,--index(Σ,,4)=--Λ,index(Σ,,5)=trim(E7)))))),
     hstack(Ξ,map(A9:A,Ξ,lambda(Λ,Δ,if(len(Δ),chooserows(ifna(filter(index(Σ,,2),isbetween(index(Σ,,1),Δ,ifna(filter(index(Σ,,2),int(index(Σ,,1))=E6+1,--index(Σ,,4)=--Λ,index(Σ,,5)=trim(E7)),E6+2),,),--index(Σ,,4)=--Λ,index(Σ,,5)=F7)),-1),)))))
```

- *make sure to tally out the output(from formula) is working good prior to applying it to other dates*
- ***format** the output cells to data+time format as by default it may come out as numbers*

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this it is functioning properly except if the user have the same login on the same time in it is giving a Error "Result should be single row"

https://imgur.com/a/CmuJS36

Comment: Try the updated formula

Comment: Hi lil help I just noticed the formula isn't capturing the logs of some employees EX:
ID-**80063** dates : Jan 13,14 didn't capture the OUT log,
ID-**190239** dates : Jan 9 didn't capture the OUT log,
ID-**200271** dates : Jan 13 didn't capture the OUT log,
ID - **220289** dates : Jan 11,15,16 didn't capture the OUT log

Comment: The formula as of now is designed to capture an **OUT** (searching both Jan 9 & Jan 10) only if an **valid IN** is captured on a given date (say Jan 9). Its best if you can post the question again & hopefully someone else will pitch in with a better alternative solution...